# send js variable to controller and return blade - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, routes

I'm developing a system on Laravel and using Google for the login. What I'm trying to do is **send the email the user sign in with** as a variable to a controller to fetch some data from an api based on the email and finally return blade.

**CODE:**

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help with how to send it to controller and routing would be appreciated :)

Comment: Use Javascript `XmlHttp Request` called `Ajax`. 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: How to adjust the routes based on that?

Comment: Nothing to adjust. Just create route as usual. But here you are not going make the request directly, You are going to make request via AJAX.